# How to connect SQLite database to retrieve data in certain interval Android Glance version 1.0.0

Tags: android, kotlin, glance

I found no information about connecting the SQLite database using the **glance** library to show data in the Widget. I have found some examples here [WeatherRepo.kt](https://github.com/android/platform-samples/blob/main/samples/user-interface/appwidgets/src/main/java/com/example/platform/ui/appwidgets/glance/weather/WeatherRepo.kt), but the database is not included, and I don't know what abstraction to use in a correct way to avoid any inconveniences like crashing or memory leaks.

I have tried some examples from previous responses, but they used old dependencies.